# I am trying to login intomoodle using Curl in drupal 7

Tags: curl, drupal, drupal-7, moodle

I am trying to login into moodle using curl.Can anybody tell me what is wrong in the code.I have made a module in which i have a submit button so that when i press submit it must login into moodle.

```
function usmancurl_submit() {
  $crl = curl_init();
  $url = "http://localhost/moodle/login/index.php";
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  $postdata = array(
    "edit[name]" => "usman",
    "edit[pass]" => "Usman5463",
    "edit[form_id]" => "user_login",
    "op" => "Log in"
  );
  // Tell curl we're going to send $postdata as the POST data
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

  $result = curl_exec($crl);
  $headers = curl_getinfo($crl);
  curl_close($crl);

  if ($headers['url'] == $url) {
    die("Cannot login.");
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you press submit?

Comment: a message shows up login failed

Comment: Why do you want to login with curl? What information do you need?

Comment: i want to make users in moodle from drupal

Comment: You can use web services to create a user - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Using_web_services - there are a list of functions here - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions -  use `core_user_create_users` to create a user.